Viplibs dzsave zsh: no matches found:
I am using dzsave on viplibs to convert a PNG to jpg-tiles for a zoomify / openseadragon project using the following prompt in terminal:
    vips dzsave file.png myzoom --layout zoomify myfiletiles --suffix.jpg[Q=30]

And all I'm getting back is:
zsh: no matches found: --suffix.jpg[Q=30]

removing --suffix.jpg[Q=30] works perfectly .... I wonder if this is an issue within my MacOS or Viplibs?

You need a space between --suffix and  .jpg I think.

Did you get this working? If so, please add an answer for other folk. Thank you.

Thank you Mark! That solved it for me! Awesome! :)
